# Failed to load JSON - Sencha Touch 2

Tags: json, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I am trying to refresh my app to show any differences in local host but the sencha CMD seems to not able to find my app.json file in the generated app folder structure. The file is deffinately there as well, but i do not know why it is tripping up with this.

Here is the log:

```
Sencha Cmd v4.0.2.67
[ERR] Failed to load JSON from /Users/username/Downloads/sencha/app.json - com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated array at line 80 column 20
```

It seems this error only occurs when an additional css file is added in the app.json file.

Thanks.

Comment: The error message says "Unterminated array at line 80 column 20". If I were you I'd have a look at line 80, column 20 of your app.json.

Comment: Post your app.json file